# dnf : how to install local packages

Tags: fedora, dnf

I just download inkscape with :

```
sudo dnf download inkscape --resolve
```

How may I install this package from the downloaded files now ?
The man page does not even include the *download* command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you use a package manager, you shouldn't bother about first downloading and then installing. You should just run:

```
sudo dnf install inkscape
```

supposing you already downloaded some packages locally and you want to install them, then you can:

```
sudo dnf install /path/to/package.rpm
```

If you have a directory full of packages that can possibly be used for installation, then you should convert that directory into a repository (using `createrepo`) and add it to `dnf` as a repository...

Comment: Thanks but I obviously tried that before ask. :) The issue is that dnf restarted to donwload everything whereas the purpose of the manoeuver was to gain some time : download packages while installing another package.. As you already understood : that just went well..

Comment: @JohnDoe I expanded my answer. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I may have to come back but I understand the sane logic of your answer, so I accepted it.

Comment: The error actually came from my misunderstanding of the command : it does not download in the cache directory as I thought but in the current directory where the command is issued.